# For memory, what should be done when you need to constantly grow a vector to an unknown upper limit?

Tags: r, arrays, memory

Suppose that you are dealing with a potentially infinite amount of data. Suppose further that you do not have this data stored in memory, but can generate individual terms at will. Finally, suppose that you want to do some experiment on this data that will involve checking a large but unknown amount of terms in a way that necessitates keeping a great many of them in memory. Toy problems with [Recamán's sequence](https://oeis.org/A005132), like "find the minimum number terms needed in that sequence for the first 25 even numbers to have appeared", are what I have in mind as typical examples.

The obvious solution to this sort of problem would be to write some code like:

```
list<-c(first term)
while([not found enough terms yet])
{
  nextTerm<-Whatever
  if(this term worked){list<-c(list,nextTerm)}
}
```

However, building a big vector like this by adding one new term at a time is your memory's worst nightmare. The alternative that I often see suggested is to pre-allocate a big vector in memory by making the first line of your code something like `list<-numeric(10^6)`, but those solutions suppose that we have some rough idea of how many terms we need to check, which isn't always the case. So what can we do when we are dealing with an ever-growing list of unknown required length?

Comment: Related: [Collecting an unknown number of results in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512371/collecting-an-unknown-number-of-results-in-a-loop); [Calculate vector whose length is not known beforehand - should I “grow” it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440778/calculate-vector-whose-length-is-not-known-beforehand-should-i-grow-it)

Comment: Instead of `list <- c(list,nextTerm)` in case `nextTerm` has a length of 1 use `list[length(list) + 1] <- nextTerm` otherwise use `list[length(list) + seq_along(nextTerm)] <- nextTerm`, what will reduce time and influences amount of  used memory.

Comment: I suspect the naive solution is the best in terms of memory. It just comes at the cost of frequent allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very popular subject in R check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45195098/5442527
Summing up:
Do not use `c()` to bind as providing value by index [ is much faster. I know that it might seem surprising that you could grow pre-allocated vector. Make an iter variable before while loop and increase the index inside the if statement.

Normally like in Python you do not have to care about it when using append. Even starting with empty list is not an problem as the list (reserved memory) grows expotentialy (x2x2x1.5x1.2...) when you pass some perimeter number of elements. Link [Over-allocating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833907/repeatedly-appending-to-a-large-list-python-2-6-6)