# How to spped up a nested loop where the second loop depend on the first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, loops, parallel-processing

Consider the following code:

```
n = 20000


def f(i, j):

    return (i+1j*j)/(i-1j*j+1)  # a sample function, not necessary this form


lst = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i, n):
        lst.append((i, j, f(i, j)))
```

since the loop is very large, I want to vectorize or speed it up. Reading other post, it seems that `itertools.product` can speed up loop, but in my case the second loop depend on the first, it seems I can't simply use it. Then how to speed it up?

I can, for example, use 4 processors.

Comment: `itertools.product` doesn't really speed up loop by much. It provide a convenient way to write nested loop as a single one. If you cannot vectorize your function, your best bet is working with something like `numba`.

Comment: One suggestion: don't grow the list dynamically. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473783/is-there-a-way-to-circumvent-python-list-append-becoming-progressively-slower

Comment: By the way, `itertools.combinations` is somewhat equivalent to your double loop, not `itertools.product`.

Comment: @QuangHoang How to vectorize a function in general?

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse That's too hard of a question. Most people would say **No way**. You have to know what your function does. Even then, vectorization might not be trivial, if at all possible.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for mentioning. I noticed combinations, which speed up a lit bit but not much.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can do it with [`np.triu_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html):

```
i, j = np.triu_indices(n)
np.stack([i, j, f(i, j)])
```

This might choke your system (since `i` and `j` will have 200M elements each for `n = 20000`) in which case you'll need `itertools`

Comment: Your solution is fast. Does it require `f` to be a "vectorized function"?

Comment: yes, it won't work if `f` isn't vectorized

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
lst = list( map ( 
  lambda item: (item[0],item[1], f(item[0],item[1] )), 
  filter( lambda item: item[0] >= item[1] ,  itertools.product(range(n),range(n))) 
))
```

However, I do not see how it can speed up loop since `itertools.product` uses a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Don't grow the list dynamically. See: [Is there a way to circumvent Python list.append() becoming progressively slower in a loop as the list grows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473783/is-there-a-way-to-circumvent-python-list-append-becoming-progressively-slower), and [Create an empty list in python with certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size).
2. Instead of a list, allocate a blank numpy array of the desired size, and fill it using your function.
3. Divide the input range into subsets, and create subprocesses to process each subset. For instance, process 1 handles 0-10000, and process 2 handles 10001-20000. The main process waits for the child processes to exit, then combines the results.

Comment: Item 1 - Yes. Item 2 - No. I believe manually edit/update numpy array elements would be slower than updating list elements.

Comment: @QuangHoang Ill try it and update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'll present an example for smaller value of *n*:

```
n = 4
```

First create a **full** array with results of your function:

```
arr = np.fromfunction(f, (n,n), dtype='complex')
```

So far the result (with reduced precision) is:

```
array([[ 0.     +0.j, -0.5    +0.5j    , -0.8    +0.4j    , -0.9    +0.3j    ],
       [ 0.5    +0.j,  0.2    +0.6j    , -0.25   +0.75j   , -0.53846+0.69231j],
       [ 0.66667+0.j,  0.5    +0.5j    ,  0.15385+0.76923j, -0.16667+0.83333j],
       [ 0.75   +0.j,  0.64706+0.41176j,  0.4    +0.7j    ,  0.12   +0.84j   ]])
```

Then, to generate your expected result, run:

```
result = [ [i,j, arr[i,j]] for i, j in zip(*np.triu_indices(n)) ]
```

The result is a list of lists containing:

```
[[0, 0, 0j]],
 [0, 1, (-0.5    +0.5j)]],
 [0, 2, (-0.8    +0.4j)],
 [0, 3, (-0.89999+0.3j)],
 [1, 1, ( 0.2    +0.6j)],
 [1, 2, (-0.25   +0.75j)],
 [1, 3, (-0.53846+0.69231j)],
 [2, 2, ( 0.15385+0.76923j)],
 [2, 3, (-0.16667+0.83333j)],
 [3, 3, ( 0.12   +0.84j)]]
```

(I also reduced the precision).

If you run into problems concerning available memory, then don't create
any temporary array, but run instead:

```
result = [ [i, j, f(i,j)] for i, j in zip(*np.triu_indices(n)) ]
```

But this variant will run significantly slower than using *np.fromfunction*.

Comment: How much memory does `arr = np.fromfunction(f, (n,n), dtype='complex')` take compared to a same sized complex number array?

Comment: The amount of memory is just the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take advantage of `numba`'s capabilities for this kind of work:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange

n = 10000
@jit(nopython=True)
def f(i, j):
    return (i+1j*j)/(i-1j*j+1)  # a sample function, not necessary this form

def loops_lst(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            lst.append((i, j, f(i, j)))
    return np.asarray(lst)
res1 = loops_lst(n)

def loops_np(n): # solution by @Daniel F
    i, j = np.triu_indices(n)
    out = np.stack([i, j, f(i, j)])
    return out.T
res2 = loops_np(n)

@jit(nopython=True,parallel=True)
def loops_nb(n):
    dim = np.sum(np.arange(1, n+1))
    out_idx = np.empty((dim,2),dtype=np.int64)
    out_f = np.empty((dim),dtype=np.complex64)
    for i in prange(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            idx = int((n*(n-1))/2 - ((n-i)*(n-i-1))/2+j)
            out_idx[idx,0] = i
            out_idx[idx,1] = j
            out_f[idx] = f(i, j)
    return out_idx, out_f

res3_ = loops_nb(n)
res3 = np.hstack((res3_[0], res3_[1][:,None]))
```

Here is the sanity check:

```
np.allclose(res1,res2)
>>> True
np.allclose(res1,res3)
>>> True
```

There follow the timings for `n=10000`:

```
# numpy triu_indices
%timeit res2 = loops_np(n)
2.32 s ± 58.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# numba
# parallel = False (and simple range instead of numba.prange)
%timeit res3_ = loops_nb(n);res3 = np.hstack((res3_[0], res3_[1][:,None]))
2.13 s ± 47.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# parallel = True
%timeit res3_ = loops_nb(n);res3 = np.hstack((res3_[0], res3_[1][:,None]))
1.46 s ± 71.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So if there is a possibility to `njit` your true function `f`, you should definitely take a look at the `numba` solution.